# How to use Mockito @InjectMocks with JUnit5 PER_CLASS lifecycle

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, mockito, junit5

Using Java or Kotlin, Junit5 and Mockito 4.x, for a Test class like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var Inner

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var Outer

    fun test1() {...}
    fun test2() {...}
}
```

it seems that MockitoExtension takes care of calling `initMocks()/openMocks`before each test, but because of PER_CLASS, test2 uses the same instance of Outer, and Mockito create a new instance of Inner, but does not inject it into Outer (because that's the semantics of initMocks/openMocks it seems).

Also sadly Mockito does not even fail with a useful error in that situation.

Is there any clean solution to this that combines PER_CLASS, `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`?

Comment: [See this thread in the Mockito repo](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1437) (looks like a problem with Mockito internally)

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a currently known limitation in Mockito (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1437).

As mitigation, users can of course use `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` with a potential performance loss, or replace `@InjectMocks` with explicitly creating a new instance of the test subject (Outer in my example) in `@BeforeEach`.